# ponteiro de uma struct dentro dela mesma

Tags: c

Quero colocar um ponteiro pra uma struct dentro dela mesma, mas o compilador esta dizendo que não conhece o tipo da struct, qual a forma correta de fazer isso?

```
    typedef struct{
        int numero;
        teste *proximo;
    }teste;
```

edit:
Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas surgiu apenas mais uma duvida, na estrutura que estou tentando replicar, com um numero e um endereço do próximo numero em sequencia, obviamente seria muito desgastante ficar acessando ponteiro por ponteiro, então fiz uma função para retornar o índice
que deseja acessar, ela deu certo, mas pelo menos com meus conhecimentos iniciantes na linguagem imagino que também era pra dar certo da forma "desgastante", mas por algum motivo o compilar diz que a diferenciação esta incompleta, só por motivos de curiosidade mesmo, por que esse erro acontece?

código:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<errno.h>



    typedef struct{
        int numero;
        struct Teste *proximo;
    }Teste;
    
    
    
    void alocaPosicoes(Teste *ptr, int quantidade){
        
        ptr->proximo = malloc(sizeof(Teste));
        ptr->numero = rand()%10;
    
        if(quantidade>1){
            alocaPosicoes(ptr->proximo, quantidade-1);
        }else{
            ptr->proximo = NULL;
        }
    
    }
    
    void imprimePosicoesStruct(Teste *ptr){
        
        for(Teste *ptr1 = ptr; ptr1!=NULL; ptr1 = ptr1->proximo){
            printf("%d", ptr1->numero);
        }
    }
    
    Teste* encontraPosicao(Teste *ptr, int posicao){
        int indice = 0;
        
        for(ptr; indice!=posicao; ptr = ptr->proximo){
            indice++;
            if(!ptr){
                return ptr;
            }
        }
    
        return ptr; 
    }
    int main(){
    
        
        Teste *ptr;
        ptr=malloc(sizeof(Teste));
    
        alocaPosicoes(ptr, 5);
        imprimePosicoesStruct(ptr);
        printf("%d", encontraPosicao(ptr, 1)->numero);
        printf("%d", ptr->proximo->numero);//o erro acontece aqui
    
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No momento que você escreve `teste` para usar dentro de sua estrutura, o compilador ainda não tem a definição completa do quê é a `typedef`. Você tem duas opções:

- Adicione a palavra `struct` antes da definição de `proximo`, para o compilador saber que trata-se de uma struct. Adicione também o nome da struct antes de abrir as chaves:

```
typedef struct teste
{
        int numero;
        struct teste* proximo;
} teste;
```

- Faça uma declaração anterior para explicitar que a palavra `teste` refere-se a uma `struct teste`:

```
typedef struct teste teste;
struct teste
{
        int numero;
        teste* proximo;
};
```